# Pandas DataFrame filter column A depending on if column B contains x for group of values in A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter the below DataFrame `df` on column `ref`, based on if for the value in `ref`, column `type` contains the value `'P'`.

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   ref type
0    1    P
1    1    C
2    1    A
3    2    C
4    3    P
5    3    P
6    4    P
7    4    A
8    5    C
9    5    A
```

Here, `ref` values 1, 3, and 4 contain **at least one row** with value `'P'` in column `type`, while 2 and 5 do not.

I am trying to filter out any rows with `ref` 2 and 5 so that the final output is:

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
   ref type
0    1    P
1    1    C
2    1    A
4    3    P
5    3    P
6    4    P
7    4    A
```

How could I do this (preferably in one step)?

Comment: does this need to work for more than 2 columns?

Comment: @JamesAndrews yes, the output contains multiple columns, but only two are relevant for the filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby('ref').filter(lambda x : ('P' in x['type'].values))
```

returns:

```
   ref type
0    1    P
1    1    C
2    1    A
4    3    P
5    3    P
6    4    P
7    4    A
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much @sacul :)